# Any Info on Tizen Mobile Application

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-simulator, tizen-native-app

I am new to Tizen Native App Development.

Can any one help me out as My Tizen Simulator is not working.

I have Installed Tizen 2.4. When I click on the Simulator it's opening as blank. Unable to see anything.

Also Any tutorial to start with will be helpfull to work with.

Comment: [Second on Google](https://developer.tizen.org/development/tutorials/native-application). With the Tizen Simulator not working, how is it not working? What have you tried?

Comment: I have Installed Tizen 2.4 when I am clicking on the Simulator its opening as blank.Unable To see anything

Comment: Launching[Run] TestApp_Debug has encountered a problem , 
Cannot Create Package

this is one error showing in my second system when I am running the application.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite  few tutorials on developer.tizen.org, have a look around there.

Seem to recall there were some oddities in some circumstances with the simulator. What are you running the SDK on?  You could also try looking at the home page for the simulator, which is at https://01.org/tizen-web-simulator.

Can you at least try if the emulator works? It should have a few less requirements than the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Tizen Web Simulator supports only web-app not native apps, native apps should be tried in the emulator or on a device. 
According to the [01.org page](https://01.org/tizen-web-simulator) not only it supports only web-apps but just Tizen 1.0 Web API

> The Tizen Web Simulator is a lightweight tool for developing mobile
>   web applications.  Extending the Google Chrome developer tools, it
>   enables running and debugging web APIs for a variety of mobile
>   platforms.  It currently supports the Tizen 1.0 Web API.